# Saving a variable globaly

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new developer and I am trying to make a button that each user can only press once and that has a counter that saves across all users. My code so far is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>replit</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
 <script>
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Join Kaiism";
btn.onclick = function counter() {
  document.write (x + 1);

};
document.body.appendChild(btn);
var x ;//global variable  
x = 0
document.write(x)

   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to save the variable x and keep it the same globally so that all users can see the total time it has been pushed?

Comment: You can take a look at window.LocalStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or use Cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: When you say globally, you are actually referring to _all users_. Typically _globally_ means available on a per client basis in the `window` object. What you want is a shared data across all sessions: you will need a server to persist that data. Client-side technology alone cannot do that for you.

Comment: You need a server and to store that. A client side cannot change another client side.

Comment: Does someone know why there is -8 as score ? This is a high negative score :o

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about between separate users, you are going to need to implement some form of online sync between users in order for this to work. I would recommend something like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), since it is very beginner friendly and for your use case will be free.

If instead you mean only users that are using the same browser and computer(which is basically just one user lol), then utilizing local storage is what you are looking for.